# How can I find the application for a MIME type on linux?

Tags: linux, mime, file-association

Is there a linux API that can find the default application for a MIME type?
Then I can use this application to open a file.

I can not use xdg-open(url) because the file format is a wrapper format and shared mime-type can only tell the wrapper MIME type. The embedded mime type can only be got from the wrapper file header.

The process would be like:
1. find embedded mime type
2. mime-open(embedded mime type, url)

Is it possible?

Many thanks!
Amanda

Comment: try your question there : http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It depends on the system. Don't have time/inclination to post an answer, but there are several ways depending whether you're using Gnome, KDE, or other. It's not pretty. I think `xdg-mime` will check correctly though.